# Not able to get an access token for my okta api service via postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, okta

I'm writing a spring boot backend in java which endpoints are secured by okta.
The application uses the okta api service app integration since only the frontend and never a user is retreiving data from it.

To get a valid access token from the okta api I followed these steps: https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/implement-grant-type/clientcreds/main/#request-for-token

Sadly all my attempts result in an error.

My postman configuration:

Okta api endpoint:
https://dev-61814681.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/token

Authentication method:
Basic auth with client id as username and client secret as password

Headers:

```
accept = application/json
cache-control = no-cache
content-type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Body:

```
grant-type = client_credentials
scope = MyDefault
```

The response:
400 bad request

It would be nice if someone could push me in the right direction with this one.

Comment: Do you mind to show the resulting request (without authorization header)? It might help to figure what's wrong with it. If you are doing that in Postman you should be able just get a cURL command for your request

Comment: curl --location 'https://dev-61814681.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/token' \
--header 'accept: application/json' \
--header 'cache-control: no-cache' \
--header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic MG9h[...]OQ==' \
--header 'Cookie: DT=DI1tM8NGUbgTbO9pYl_O16rEA; JSESSIONID=C1CEE3CAB5B197C225A8928586850E9E; t=default' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=MyDefault'

Comment: <html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by doing the following:

I took the cURL pictured at https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/implement-grant-type/clientcreds/main/#request-for-token

[image]

After that I inserted my Okta domain, added my authorization (client id and client secret written in the same line seperated by ':' and encoded as base64) and updated the scope from customScope to my own custom scope.

I imported all of that into postman by pressing the import button and inserting the raw text.

[image]

Now everithing works fine.

Comment: You see the difference now in your body?

Comment: Yes thank you. You pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Point to note, you are using "customScope" here, yet when asked, you said "MyDefault" was your current configuration. That was also why it was not giving any useful errors at all previously.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `grant-type` instead of what you wrote (grand-type).

Also, make sure you have defined the "MyDefault" scope in your Okta API app and that it has the necessary permissions for your client to access the endpoints it requires.

Hopefully the typo fixes the issue in this case.

Comment: Fixed the typo but nothing changed. The MyDefault scope is defined with following parameters: UserConsent = No, BlockServices = No, DefaultScope = No, MetadataPublish = Yes.